# Three.js - pananorama application into reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I am interested in trying to jsfiddle this application.  I like to see how to improve this application to avoid the tearing that is happening in the demo.

//latest js fiddle - but has broken 404 on the images.
https://jsfiddle.net/7xzd92s5/64/

http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_panorama

eventually turn it into a reactjs component.

```
var ThreePan= React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>ThreePan</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( < Hello name = "ThreePan" / > ,
  document.getElementById('ThreePan')
);
```

//the three.js example code

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
        var geometry, material, mesh;
        var target = new THREE.Vector3();

        var lon = 90, lat = 0;
        var phi = 0, theta = 0;

        var touchX, touchY;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var sides = [
                {
                    url: 'textures/cube/Bridge2/posx.jpg',
                    position: [ -512, 0, 0 ],
                    rotation: [ 0, Math.PI / 2, 0 ]
                },
                {
                    url: 'textures/cube/Bridge2/negx.jpg',
                    position: [ 512, 0, 0 ],
                    rotation: [ 0, -Math.PI / 2, 0 ]
                },
                {
                    url: 'textures/cube/Bridge2/posy.jpg',
                    position: [ 0,  512, 0 ],
                    rotation: [ Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI ]
                },
                {
                    url: 'textures/cube/Bridge2/negy.jpg',
                    position: [ 0, -512, 0 ],
                    rotation: [ - Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI ]
                },
                {
                    url: 'textures/cube/Bridge2/posz.jpg',
                    position: [ 0, 0,  512 ],
                    rotation: [ 0, Math.PI, 0 ]
                },
                {
                    url: 'textures/cube/Bridge2/negz.jpg',
                    position: [ 0, 0, -512 ],
                    rotation: [ 0, 0, 0 ]
                }
            ];

            for ( var i = 0; i < sides.length; i ++ ) {

                var side = sides[ i ];

                var element = document.createElement( 'img' );
                element.width = 1026; // 2 pixels extra to close the gap.
                element.src = side.url;

                var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
                object.position.fromArray( side.position );
                object.rotation.fromArray( side.rotation );
                scene.add( object );

            }

            renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            //

            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false );

            document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            var movementX = event.movementX || event.mozMovementX || event.webkitMovementX || 0;
            var movementY = event.movementY || event.mozMovementY || event.webkitMovementY || 0;

            lon -= movementX * 0.1;
            lat += movementY * 0.1;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

            document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {

            camera.fov -= event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        }

        function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var touch = event.touches[ 0 ];

            touchX = touch.screenX;
            touchY = touch.screenY;

        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var touch = event.touches[ 0 ];

            lon -= ( touch.screenX - touchX ) * 0.1;
            lat += ( touch.screenY - touchY ) * 0.1;

            touchX = touch.screenX;
            touchY = touch.screenY;

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            lon +=  0.1;
            lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
            phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
            theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

            target.x = Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
            target.y = Math.cos( phi );
            target.z = Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );

            camera.lookAt( target );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2014/12/10/html5-webgl-360-degrees-panorama-viewer-with-three-js/) helped me to in my case. i used most of the same code and used refs for accessing DOM nodes. Also you should rename the render method to some other function names as it conflicts with react's render method.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7xzd92s5/71/ incorporate this mock - but have cross domain issues with the images

Comment: you can do this `THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';`  and append any random query string in image url. ex: `var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader('[URL+?x=123]');`

Comment: I've added the cross origin var - but its not taking any effect - https://jsfiddle.net/7xzd92s5/72/

Comment: Hey @TheOldCounty please follow [link](https://codeshare.io/PtOwg). It is working for me in my project code, i have just copy pasted it there. So you will have to do a figure out the thing you were missing. It will take time to make a working fiddle.

Comment: I don't see any images in yours?

Comment: It is passed as a prop, which i have declared on top of the constructor.